# Intellisense is not showing suggestions from all available libraries

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, code-completion

Intellisense is only suggesting classes that are imported via `using` statement.

For example if I type `file` it does not suggest `FileOpenPicker` unless I have imported the namespace `using Windows.Storage.Pickers`.

If i had Resharper it would suggest me `FileOpenPicker` and would import the required namespace as well. But I dont have Resharper for now.

It is hard, because i don't fully remember class names and namespaces, I just know them partially.

How do I enable this option in visual studio? (current version 15.8.2 in a uwp project)

Comment: Hi, we can report this suggestion to the VS Product Team in here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may do it in future. let me know if you did it already :)

Comment: Hi, I have reported this user voice in here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/417680/vs-text-editorintellisense-intellisense-should-lis.html, you can follow or add a comment in there, if they have any plans about this in the future, I will also update it in here, thanks for your understanding.